# How do you add a dependency to a JBoss EJB with a generated WebService?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to deploy an EJB in JBoss that uses the @WebService annotation. However, the EJB has a dependency on an EJB in another ear. By adding the @Depends annotation, the EJB start is delayed until after the ear is loaded, but it appears the WebService generator is still trying to start up the generated WAR as soon as it sees the annotation.

Is there anything similar to @Depends for the generated JBossWS that I can add?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may need to do is configure the deployment order that JBoss is using. I know this is possible and I think it is what people I work with have done for dependencies like this. If this link doesn't help, you will want to search for something dealing with JBoss deployment order and how to set the order. I had JBoss training a while back and I know this is a solution that is taught.

[JBoss Deployment Order](http://corelabs.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/how-to-alter-jboss-deployment-order/)